# Apache: Is the password protection in a .htaccess file always processed first?

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, 301-redirect

Last week I did a relaunch on a website and today I have realized that the staging subdomain got indexed by Google. I want to avoid this mistake in the future and track down the error source.

I assume that it has to do with the `.htaccess` file and cached redirects.

The .htaccess file is structured like that

```
# A bunch of 301 redirects
Redirect 301 /url https://stage.example.com/url 
Redirect 301 /url1 https://stage.example.com/url1 
Redirect 301 /url2 https://stage.example.com/url2

# Now the password protection
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /customer/homepages/30/544361357/htdocs/example/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Could it be that the redirects are processed before the password protection?

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file? (Those redirects imply that this is not the `.htaccess` file that is "protecting" your `stage.example.com` subdomain?)

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your staging site was indexed has at least as much, if not more so, to do with the lack of access controls on `https://stage.example.com` ...

It could be that a `Redirect` directive on your main site was responsible for disclosing the URL, but as far as I know access controls are applied by Apache before the `Redirect` is allowed, regardless of the order in which those two different classes of directives are listed in your `.htaccess` file.